# Creating a bitfield structure in lua like in C programming

Tags: lua

Is it possible in lua to do bitfields like in C?

```
struct a = 
{
    uint8 var1 : 5;
    uint8 var2 : 3;
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you want to implement bit-wise operations, Lua 5.3 has [native support](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.2) for that, no need to use bit fields (which are already poorly defined in C anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua as a language is generally not intended for the kinds of scenarios where low-level bitfield manipulation is a common, or even uncommon occurrence. As such, it does not have language features to do this sort of thing.

Now, Lua 5.3, with its direct support for integers as a pseudo-distinct type, has ways of doing direct bit manipulation. So you can achieve the same effect as a bitfield. But there is no nice, simple syntax for it. The scenarios where you need to save memory or directly access a binary data format (the two primary uses of bitfields) are not a common enough scenario for Lua's intended use cases to be deserving of special syntax.